# Django annotate model and filter for specific value

Tags: python, django, django-annotate

I'm trying to get into djangos annotate, but can't quite figure out how it works exactly.

I've got a function where I'd like to annotate a queryset of customers, filter them and return the number of customers

```
def my_func(self):
    received_signatures = self.customer_set.annotate(Count('registrations').filter().count()
```

Now for the filter part, thats where I have a problem figuring out how to do that. The thing I'd like to filter for is my `received_signatures`, which is a function that is being called in my customer.py

```
def received_signatures(self):
    signatures = [reg.brought_signature for reg in self.registrations.all() if reg.status == '1_YES']
    if len(signatures): 
        return all(signatures)
    else:
       return None
```

`brough_signature` is a DB Field

So how can I annotate the queryset, filter for the received_signatures and then return a number?

Relevant Model Information:

```
class Customer(models.Model):
    brought_signature = models.BooleanField(u'Brought Signature', default=False)


class Registration(models.Model):
    brought_signature = models.BooleanField(u'Brought Signature', default=False)
    status = models.CharField(u'Status', max_length=10, choices=STATUS_CHOICES, default='4_RECEIVED')
```

Note: A participant and a registration can have `brought_signature`. I have a setting in my program which allows me to either A) mark only brought_signature at my participant (which mean he brought the signature for ALL his registrations) or B) mark brought_signature for every registration he has

For this case Option B) is relevant. With my `received_signatures` I check if the customer has brought every signature for every registration where his status is "1_YES" and I want to count all the customers who did so and return a number (which I then use in another function for a pygal chart)

Comment: But if you *count* the number of `Customer`s, then what is the use of *annotating* these first?

Comment: If I understand it correctly, you want to `Count` the number of `Customer`s that have at least one `Registration`, where `status == '1_YES'` right, and check if all have `brough_signature = 1`?

Comment: Is it possible to (a) share the (relevant) parts of the models, and (b) describe *what* you want, not *how* to do it (the XY problem).

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Exactly, count every customer with at least one registration, where the status is 1_YES and if they brought all their signatures (some customers can have multiple signatures) I'll update my question

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I added some more info, hope thats better to understand now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand it correctly, you want to check if *all* the `Registration`s for a given `Customer` with `status == '1_YES` should have as attribute `.brought_signature = True`, and there should be *at least* such value. There are several approaches for this.

We can do this by writing it like:

```
received_signatures = self.customer_set.filter(
    registration__status='1_YES'
).annotate(
    minb=Min('registration__brought_signature')
).filter(
    minb__gt=0
).count()
```

So what we here do is first `.filter(..)` on the `registration`s that have as status `1_YES`, next we calculate for every customer a value `minb` that is the *minimum* of `brought_signature` of these `Registration`s. So in case one of the `brought_signature`s of the related `Registration`s is `False` (in a database that is usually `0`), then `Min(..)` is `False` as well. In case all `brought_signature`s are `True` (in a database that is usually `1`), then the result is `1`, we can then filter on the fact that `minb` should thus be greater than `0`.

So `Customer`s with *no* `Registration` will *not* be counted, `Customer`s with no `Registration` with status `1_YES`, will not be counted, `Customer`s with `Registration`s for which there is a `Registration` with status `1_YES`, but with `brough_signature` will not be counted. Only `Customer`s for which *all* `Registration`s that have status `1_YES` (not per se *all* `Registration`s) have `brough_signature = True` are counted.